# How to identify a active contentEditable div inside another div which has multiple contentEditable divs

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

Here is the simple markup:

```html
<div id="myId1">
    <div id="contentEdit1" contentEditable="true></div>
    <div id="contentEdit2" contentEditable="true></div>
    ...
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery code:

```js
$('#myId1 ' + '[contenteditable="true"]').on('keydown', function(ev) {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

The problem is that the event handler is not triggered at all when I start editing any of the contentEditable divs. Any thoughts?

EDIT: I had a typo in my question. I had missed the single quotes around [contenteditable="true"] and the closing parenthesis of console.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('#myId1 [contenteditable="true"]').on('keydown', function(ev) {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/vYGgEZj

Actually you have a wrong element selector `'#myId1 ' + [contenteditable="true"]` + do not close the parenthesis after `console.log`.

Comment: My problem was in the parent selector I am generating dynamically.  Your answer clarified that my approach was not incorrect and that I had to look elsewhere.

Comment: Is there a way to find out which contenteditable div has focus knowing the selector of the parent using CSS? I know one can iterate through all of them using Javascript and see if it is in focus. I know this is a different question but if you could answer, that would help.

Comment: @Sunny Did you try `:focus`? Docs - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus The following demo set focused `div` in red. Have a look - https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/gOrgrep